# Population growth model word problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question: There are two non competing populations with birth rates, death rates, and starting populations as follows. $B1(t)=\frac{1}{t+1}; D1(t)=\frac{1}{10}; P1=2; B2(t)=\frac{2}{t+1}; D2(t)=\frac{1}{10}; P2=1;$ Given these conditions find how long it takes the second population to surpass the first and find how long it takes the second population to double the first.

The formula: The textbook gives the equation for $P(t)$ as $P\times \exp\int(B(t)-D(t))\mathrm{d}t$

What I have tried: I tried to figure their population equations out and set them equal to one another to solve the first part of the question.  I got...

$2\exp{\int \left(\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{10}\right) \mathrm{d}t} = \exp{\int \left(\frac{2}{t+2}-\frac{1}{10}\right) \mathrm{d}t}$

simplifying I got $2\exp\left(\ln(t+1)-\frac{1}{10t}\right)=\exp\left(2\ln(t+2)-\frac{1}{10t}\right)$

more algebra got me $2(t+1)e^{\frac{-t}{10}} = (t+2)^2\times e^{\frac{-t}{10}}$

simplified is $2t+2=t^2+2t+2$

$0=t^2+2t+2$ which does not have a real solution

I cannot for the life of me figure out where my mistake is if you could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: If P1=1 and P2=2 the second population surpasses the first population already at time t=0. // Your exp[int(2/(t+2)-1/10 dt] should probably read exp[int(2/(t+1)-1/10 dt], which hugely simplifies the rest.

Comment: yeah that is part of what I don't understand the textbook definitely say that the birth rate of the second population is 2/(t+2) i probably should have mentioned that it also gives the answers part 1 is t=2(1+root(2)) and part 2 is t=2(3+2root(3))

Comment: oh yeah you are right in my description p1=2 and p2=1 i screwed up but my equations are still right thats why the left hand side of my first equality has the 2 before the exp[] part

Comment: @numtheory1555242 You may like to consider formatting your working correctly via Latex [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) is a good place to learn how that is done

Comment: I understand that $B_1(t)=1/(t+1)$, $D_1(t)=1/10$, $P_1=2$, $B_2(t)=2/(t+2)$, $D_2(t)=1/10$, $P_2=1$, then coincidence occurs when $$2\cdot\exp(\log(t+1)-\log(0+1)-t/10)=1\cdot\exp(2\log(t+2)-2\log(0+2)-t/10),$$ that is $2(t+1)=(t+2)^2/4$, that is $t^2-4t-4=0$, that is, $t=2+\sqrt{8}$. Surely now you can solve the second part.

Comment: Okay I can see how that works out to the answer I just dont understand where "log(0+1)" and "2log(0+2)" come from on each side. Does it have something to do with needing to solve for a constant after integrating?

Comment: Well yes, for example, $$\int_0^tB_1(s)ds=\left.\log(s+1)\right|_{s=0}^{s=t}=\log(t+1)-\log(0+1).$$ (Unrelated: Please use @.)